# php - Calling a function from a class within a parent class

Tags: php, oop

I have a parent class, that calls a new facebook class within it.  However, I then have another class that extends the parent, and tries to read the facebook class within it, but it dies everytime.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: also what error message does it issue when failing?

Comment: See Mr. Yang's response below, he hit it on the dot.

Answer (score 4):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that your subclass is not calling the parent constructor, so the facebook class is not being created.

If you're in PHP5, try adding `parent::__construct();` to the subclass's constructor, possibly with some extra parameters. Otherwise, you might need to do: `$this->SuperclassName();` with some extra parameters as well.

Comment: +1 for psychic debugging skills. Wish I had some too but I'm stuck with xdebug and `var_dump()`

Comment: +1 for psychic debugging skills and hinting the parent constructor call, I need to learn psychic debugging skills

Comment: So far no go yet sadly.  I added the parent class construct, but that didn't go through.  I have a few more ideas that kicked into my mind.

Comment: What test did you conduct to determine my answer was correct?

Comment: from within the new class under the primary class, i set it to parent::__construct(), which just died too.  I however set it to extend the primary class, which didn't die, but still could not be called from the class that extended the primary

Comment: However, If I set up a class variable that = to the new Facebook class (under the master); There ought to be a way for it to work

Comment: I recommend turning on error reporting. Errors are useful for debugging.

Comment: Here's the error I get back "Fatal error: Call to a member function api() on a non-object in /home/myfbcourses/app/modules/courseactionC.php on line 15"

Comment: line15#  $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment );

Comment: Well, here's the thing that makes it weirder.  When this extended class is constructed, it successfully runs the facebook API.  I have a checklogin part on the primary constructor that make's sure the user session is valid.  So when the extended class opens, it runs that check through and validates.

Comment: I took another route; I implemented the facebook post functions directly on the primary class.